# Is it possible to add a column to the Site Content and use this column as a filter it in the PnP-SearchFilters webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add a column to the site content of a site:

[image]

and use it as a filter in the PnP-Searchfilters webpart:

[image]

Gr. P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the Site Contents? As in Libraries, Lists, etc? No. But based on your screenshot, I assume you mean the Site Pages library. In which case, yes!

You can add a column to the Site Pages library like any other library. Once it has been crawled (you can request a crawl from Library Settings > Advanced Settings) you should be able to locate it as a crawled property. You'll need to map that crawled property to one of the RefinableString (or whatever type) managed properties to use it in the webpart.

There can be several delays until the managed property truly returns data and it can be a bit unpredictable in SharePoint Online. It can be pretty frustrating. Hopefully, things will resolve relatively quickly within 15-20 minutes but I've seen it take a few days.